# Matrix multiplication in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have numeric data stored in two DataFrames x and y. The inner product from numpy works but the dot product from pandas does not.

```
In [63]: x.shape
Out[63]: (1062, 36)

In [64]: y.shape
Out[64]: (36, 36)

In [65]: np.inner(x, y).shape
Out[65]: (1062L, 36L)

In [66]: x.dot(y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-76c015be254b> in <module>()
----> 1 x.dot(y)

C:\Programs\WinPython-64bit-2.7.3.3\python-2.7.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in dot(self, other)
    888             if (len(common) > len(self.columns) or
    889                     len(common) > len(other.index)):
--> 890                 raise ValueError('matrices are not aligned')
    891 
    892             left = self.reindex(columns=common, copy=False)

ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

Is this a bug or am I using pandas wrong?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Not only must the shapes of `x` and `y` be correct, but also
the column names of `x` must match the index names of `y`. Otherwise
this code in `pandas/core/frame.py` will raise a ValueError:

```
if isinstance(other, (Series, DataFrame)):
    common = self.columns.union(other.index)
    if (len(common) > len(self.columns) or
        len(common) > len(other.index)):
        raise ValueError('matrices are not aligned')
```

If you just want to compute the matrix product without making the column names of `x` match the index names of `y`, then use the NumPy dot function:

```
np.dot(x, y)
```

---

The reason why the column names of `x` must match the index names of `y` is because the pandas `dot` method will reindex `x` and `y` so that if the column order of `x` and the index order of `y` do not naturally match, they will be made to match before the matrix product is performed:

```
left = self.reindex(columns=common, copy=False)
right = other.reindex(index=common, copy=False)
```

The NumPy `dot` function does no such thing. It will just compute the matrix product based on the values in the underlying arrays.

---

Here is an example which reproduces the error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['col{}'.format(i) for i in range(36)]
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1062, 36)), columns=columns)
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((36, 36)))

print(np.dot(x, y).shape)
# (1062, 36)

print(x.dot(y).shape)
# ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

Comment: Good call, I would have never guessed the names would need to match. This saved me a few hours!